# iOS Firebase Dynamic Links not working for URL's that are percent encoded

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have set up DynamicLinks on iOS and both the "app installed" case and the "app not installed" case route URL's correctly. The only problem is that when I have a url formatted link `...?link=https://example.com/search/category%20name` and the app is **not** installed, the openUrl method in AppDelegate does not get called.

I experienced a bug earlier when I tried to pull the `link` parameter out of the dynamic link it removed the percent encoding and url creation would fail unless I added the percent encoding back. My guess is that this is what is happening when firebase tries to read back the URL from storage.

Has anyone else experienced this or is this a Firebase bug.